# I have multiple dictionaries in one variable. How to convert them into pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

**I have multiple dictionaries in one variable. How to convert them into pandas dataframe?**

```
def fetch_movie_info(dataframe_idx):
    info = df.iloc[dataframe_idx]
    meta_dict = {}
    meta_dict['Title'] = info['Title']
    meta_dict['Plot'] = info['Plot']
    return meta_dict
    
def search(query, top_k, index, model):
    t=time.time()
    query_vector = model.encode([query])
    top_k = index.search(query_vector, top_k)
    print('Results in Total Time: {}'.format(time.time()-t))
    top_k_ids = top_k[1].tolist()[0]
    top_k_ids = list(np.unique(top_k_ids))
    results =  [fetch_movie_info(idx) for idx in top_k_ids]
    return results
```

The above are the two functions. We will use them in the below code

```
query="Artificial Intelligence based action movie"
results=search(query, top_k=3, index=index, model=model)

print("")
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

The output for the above code is :

Results in Total Time: 0.02393507957458496

```
{'Title': 'Ulsaha Committee', 'Plot': 'The film is about a school drop out whose pursuit for amazing scientific inventions lands him in trouble.'}
{'Title': 'Orders Are Orders', 'Plot': 'A film production company decides to make a new science fiction film in an army barracks, using the soldiers as extras. This does not go down well with the commanding officer, who attempts to make life as difficult as possible for the film crew.'}
{'Title': 'Daughter of Shanghai', 'Plot': 'Lan Ying Lin and government agent Kim Lee battle alien smugglers.'}
```

**How to convert the above multiple dictionaries into pandas dataframe?
When i'm trying to pd.DataFrame(results), it's returning an error**

```
for result in results:
    print(pd.DataFrame(result))
```

And the error it's returning is :

```
~\t5\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in extract_index(data)
    389 
    390         if not indexes and not raw_lengths:
--> 391             raise ValueError("If using all scalar values, you must pass an index")
    392 
    393         if have_series:

ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

I'm expecting output like

```
    Title               Plot    
0   Ullasamga Utsahamga Dhanalakshmi a.k.a. Dhana (Sneha Ullal) is the...
1   Undertow            Following the death of his wife Audrey, John M...
2   Along Came Jones    Easygoing Melody Jones (Gary Cooper) and his f...
```

Comment: What error ? Please [edit] and add it. Because it should work normally

Comment: Edited, can you please check.

Comment: You do not try `pd.DataFrame(results)` at all but `pd.DataFrame(result)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass all `results` at once, to build the `DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd

results = [{'Title': 'Ulsaha Committee', 'Plot': 'The ... trouble.'},
           {'Title': 'Orders Are Orders', 'Plot': 'A ... crew.'},
           {'Title': 'Daughter of Shanghai', 'Plot': 'Lan ...smugglers.'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
print(df)
```

```
                  Title               Plot
0      Ulsaha Committee   The ... trouble.
1     Orders Are Orders        A ... crew.
2  Daughter of Shanghai  Lan ...smugglers.
```